# Set Application to cover area above taskbar, not over or under

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there an existing function to place fullscreen window to cover full area above taskbar so taskbar is visible?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Player Settings -> Resolution](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsStandalone.html#Resolution)

> **Fullscreen Mode** 
> Choose the full-screen mode. This defines the default window mode at startup.

This is only possible on `MAC`:

> **Maximized Window (Mac only)**
>    Set the app window to the operating system’s definition of “maximized”. On macOS, this means a full-screen window with an auto-hidden menu bar and dock. This option is only supported on macOS; on other platforms, the setting falls back to Fullscreen Window.

Comment: You didn't even read